# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot after AMD Radeon (radeon VCE init error -22)

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

I have installed AMD Radeon graphic card driver, following manual from their website. After rebooting the system, it stuck in endless loop showing `[OK] Started LSB: Apache 2 web server.` in first line and then `radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).` adding this new line with this same message every few seconds (but with different code on start of a line).

I have searched a little bit and found that I should disable the AMD Radeon in the BIOS and boot with Intel's graphic (because I have dual graphics Intel/Radeon). But once I have entered the BIOS, I wasn't able to find this option. 
On some older posts I have read that this option doesn't even exist in Dell's boot. My laptop is Dell Vostro 15 3000 Series.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone face this problem also, here is the solution which worked for me:

- Boot Live CD (I was using Mint, but it's not obligatory, can use other distribution probably)
- Open terminal and type `sudo su`
- use `sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt` (instead of `*` you have to find out on which partition your root is stored, and use it)
- And then with `chroot /mnt` you can change root to use it's terminal
- After that type the command for uninstalling driver which made you problem, that comand for me was `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`

Hope this will save hours for somebody, cause I was trying a lot solutions for few hours today and none of them worked, but this one.